# How can these people fight these monsters?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, alternate-earth, tactics, strategy

On an alternate earth, lethal Pliosaurs size creatures infest the ocean, making sea travel impossible. Their cousin species tries to invade the surface every five years.
The advantages of this monsters are:

1. **Healing factor**: The average creature has a healing factor allowing it to survive life threatening injuries.
2. **Superior Strength**: the average monster can lift 4,000 lb (1,810 kg) on a bench press, and have a bite of  3,700 PSI.
3. **Superior Speed** : They can all run at about 80kph (50mph) for extended periods of time.
4. **Hard Skeletons** : Their bones are harder than alumina ceramics. Their teeth and claws can easily tear apart steel.
5. **Protective shell**: Each has a shell that acts as armor, capable of withstanding knives and low-caliber bullets.
6. **High senses** : Their sense of hearing is sensitive enough to detect even the slightest noise at 1 kHz, they can smell an enemy from 20 miles away, and have a vision that is eight times sharper than a human's.
7. **Numbers**:They heavily outnumber the human population(with a population estimate in billions), for each human soldier they have three.
8. **Toxic fumes**: Some units are capable of releasing a toxin so powerful that it is capable of killing an elephant in a few seconds, only to melt it down to its bones later.

That said, they have certain weaknesses;

1. **No sense of self preservation**: They do not recognize obvious dangers or traps, they throw themselves into the meat grinder by the hundreds, the only exception is when they lose more than a half of their forces, in that moment they retreat to the ocean to resupply.
2. **Not very smart**: The only strategy they have is to rush into the enemy without taking any cover, using their numbers to overwhelm the humans. They are a bunch of wild animals that use their instincts to survive.
3. **Lack of biomass** : their healing factor is not magic. Each time they are injured, they burn energy to heal. Eventually, several injuries will end up affecting their performance and kill them.
4. **Radiation**: radiation with its ability to kill cells is a great Achilles heel.
5. **Fire**: Fire like radiation is very effective.
6. **Advanced technological enemy**: Humany is more advanced than current earth with a couple of decades. The average soldier are genetically augmented to Olympian level. They also have  developed adavanced alloys, exoskeletons, railguns, and high tech drones.
7. **Overhelmed senses**: Their advanced senses are a double-edged sword. Loud sounds, bright lights, or strong smells can confuse or hurt them.
8. **Pheromones**: A mixture of chemical substances are capable of attracting or distracting these creatures.
9. Humanity have prep time

So the answer is: How can these people fight these monsters? What type of strategy, tactic or technology would be used?.

Comment: "Look at my super awesome, invincible killing machine of doom who outnumber the human at least 3 to 1! How does humanity survive?". They don't. They turbo-die. That's it.

Comment: Regarding the post, some feedback:
- "Their bones are harder than different types of ceramic" does not really bring any precision or valuable information. You could replace ceramic by paper and we would not be more informed.
- "Each has a shell that acts as armor, capable of withstanding knives and low-caliber bullets." Would not list that as an advantage since the vast majority of army use bigger guns than low-caliber bullets for obvious reasons. Also, you don't try to knife fight something that strong, you die, so knife resistant is a bit irrelevant here. (1/2)

Comment: - Radiation and fire: that's a tad more complex than that. Also, it's a "weakness" for most living beings as far as I know. If you want to guide us to humans using nuke and flame-throwers, say that the kind to answer you look for would preferably use that. - "other special gadgets" could be anything, not informative.
Your post feature two questions, we try to keep it to one per post. Hope this help rewriting it.(2)

Comment: One missing piece of information is how big a typical example of these monsters is.  (Please don't say "leviathan-sized", or you can expect a long conversation about the squared-cubed rule.)

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding. The [help/on-topic] states, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story. ...  If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." One measure of what can be asked is, if you're asking about the decisions or actions of characters (e.g., how to use a weapon), it's off-topic.

Comment: "Leviathan-sized" would not be very helpful since the size of a leviathan is not defined. I imagine anything ranging from the size of a whale to... well... I don't know. That just means big. For all we know, they could be kilometer long. Applying square law to that is off topic since there is a major dose of handwaving here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevauch%C3%A9e**

These things are heavy from the armor and each one expends huge amounts of energy performing feats of strength as described in the OP.  And there are huge numbers of them.  They are not magic - they require energy to heal, also from OP.  These creatures must have advanced agriculture to support their size and energy needs.

Your humans will attack their agriculture.  Fortunately the humans are advanced and can attack from the air using planes and bombs.  The bombs contain biocides intended to wipe out the crops of these creatures.

Bombs full of nerve gas might be good to add too.  I was thinking this could induce the creatures to hide and not try to save their crops but I forgot that they have no sense of self preservation.  The nerve gas will be fine.

Maybe the nerve gas will also get rid of those pesky leviathans so the humans can learn to surf.   Or just use regular bombs.  Or cruise missiles if they are the kind that jumps out of the water so high that they bite planes which seems like this kind of fiction.

Comment: Did you take into account that apparently, these creatures live underwater? Not criticizing, just not entirely knowledgeable about the efficiency of nerve gas/diffusion of nerve agent underwater.

Comment: @Nyakouai it isn't entirely clear whether the "cousins" live in the water or not.  It would be very strange for a sea creature to develop the ability to run on land at 80 kph for extended periods of time, there's just no evolutionary justification.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 "when they lose more than a half of their forces, in that moment they retreat to the ocean to resupply." - there is no evolutionary justification for anything in here. These are fictional super predators, and that's about the justification.

Comment: To make this brief. The true nature of this creatures is artifcial, is not a product of evolution.

Comment: Yeah I got that they lived in the water.  I called the weapon nerve gas because I don’t know what the water equivalent would be called.  Nerve juice?

Answer (score 1):

## Biological Warfare

The creatures' doom is spelled out in point #2 of their weaknesses.  If they're just animals, we can kill them.  We're very good at that.  We're already concerned that CRISPR/CAS-9 will give people the ability to create tailored viruses that do what we want.  Give us a century's advances in the biological sciences, and no reservation about *using* these tools for war - and prep time, that most valuable asset - and we can have every Creature from the Black Ocean dead from a healing-factor-induced Turbo Fever before they ever leave the ocean.

(Given that their healing factor burns energy, rather than a fever killing them, it might simply starve them to death.  Either way, humanity just has to worry about billions of dead creatures polluting the ocean of their newly made-safe world.)